# When do dynamic IPv6 addresses for Azure load balancer front-end configurations change?

Tags: azure, cloud, ipv6, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer

I need a static ip address for IPv6 on Azure, but it looks like only dynamic IPv6 addresses are supported. I'm wondering about the relative stability of a dynamic IPv6 address for Azure load balancers. How often will it change?

In the Azure Docs, it says that dynamic ip addresses for VMs change when the vm is restarted, stopped, or deallocated. How does this work for load balancers, since they are not restarted or stopped?

If I have a load balancer with an availability set of vms as a backend pool, will the public IPv6 front-end ip configuration be relatively stable even if it's technically "dynamic", as long as I don't change the backend pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering about the relative stability of a dynamic IPv6 address
>   for Azure load balancers. How often will it change?

For now, IPv6 allocation static method are **not** supported.

Any unreserved IP address(IPv4 and IPv6) will remain **static** if you:
1.**Don't delete** the public IP object associated with the load balancer.
2.Maintain **at least 1 VM** in the backend pool.

So, if we don't delete public IP address or disassociate it, and keep a VM running in the backend pool, we will keep the Public IPv6 address(will not change).

Comment: Thank you, Jason! The behavior you describe makes sense--just for more detail, I also saw that the VMs cannot be "stopped", so we must maintain at least 1 Active VM in the backend pool. So, if for some reason, all of our machines were shut down for awhile (such as in disaster scenario or maintenance), we would also lose the IPv6 address.